# Exception save file - Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, exception, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, fileoutputstream

I am downloading an image from an URL and trying to share it with an Intent from a notification button.

I set the read and write permissions in the Manifest and checking it for Marshmallow devices too. I accept the storage permission but I can't share the image because it doesn't save the file. Why?

My code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] splitLink = link.getText().toString().split("/");
            String imageName = splitLink[splitLink.length-1];
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), imageName);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                saveImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
                fileOutputStream.flush(); // Optimizació: per borrar fluxe de bytes de sortida i obligar als que estan en memoria a escriures
                fileOutputStream.close();
                file.setReadable(true, false); // Per permetre acces de lectura a totes les aplicacions
                if (!file.mkdirs()) Log.e("Crear carpeta 3", "No rutlla");

            } catch (Exception e) {Log.e("Guardar imatge 3", "No rutlla"); e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
E/Guardar imatge 3: No rutlla
System.err:java.io.FileNotFoundException:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/01.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: currently, complete grant permission in your app?

Comment: Yes, the permission it is granted.

Comment: `it seems like I have no acces to the directory`. ?? Please explain 'seems'.

Comment: There is a catch block in your code. But if there is a catch you do not inform the user with a toast. Nor do you stop with the code. You should not call those intents then.

Comment: The problem is that the file is not created.